# How to imply “to“ to 2 verbs?

Tags: verbs

When I want to use `to` implying to 2 verbs, do I need to use `to` again? For example, which one is true?

```
I'm eager to improve myself and to be involved in r&d activities.
```

or

```
I'm eager to improve myself and be involved in r&d activities.
```

Comment: The first one is more grammatically correct, but the second one is also acceptable and you will see this usage a lot.  I'll leave it for someone with a more formal understanding of English to explain why.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Thank you for the advice. Currently, I can not upvote as I'm new in this community, but I appreciated your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential difference, in that if you were to include 'both' in your sentence, the repetition of 'to' would not be optional:

> I'm eager both to improve myself and to be involved in r&d activities.

Hence the repetition of 'to' suggest that you are referring to more than one thing about which you are eager.

While your second sentence might omit 'to' for no other reason than economy, it could also be taken to suggest that your meaning is similar to the following:

> I'm eager to improve myself by being involved in r&d activities.

This is not a steadfast rule, but the second sentence is open to such an interpretation.  It's like saying 'I like bread and butter' (together), as opposed to saying 'I like both bread and butter' (but not necessarily together).

Comment: I got the point. I meant that I want to improve myself, and I also want to be involved in r&d activities; not improving myself by being involved in r&d activities. So I shall go on with the first option, thank you for the answer. (Sorry for not being able to upvote)